# Split the query string with repeatative special characters using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my String

```
Declare @qstr as varchar(max)='hireteammember.aspx?empemail=kuldeep@asselsolutions.com&empid=376&empname=kuldeep&adminname=TMA1&term=5&teamid=161&contactid=614¥1&WP=100¥5¥Months&Amt=500&DueDay=5&StrDt=12/31/2013&MemCatg=Employees&StrTm=21:05&PlnHrs=5&WrkDays=true¥true¥true¥true¥true¥false¥false'
```

I want to extract the values of empid,empname,adminname,term,teamid,contactid,WP,Months,Dueday,StrDt,MemCatgmStrTm,PlnHrs,WrkDays and assign them to new variables

I have used

```
select ( SUBSTRING(@qstr,CHARINDEX('=',@qstr)+1,CHARINDEX('&',@qstr)-CHARINDEX('=',@qstr)-1)))
```

but only getting the 'empemail' , for the next occurance of special char '&' , not able to get the values of further terms ,  if i am using '&' in spite of '=' .

Help me to split the whole string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitQueryString (@s varchar(8000))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH splitter_cte AS (
      SELECT CHARINDEX('&', @s) as pos, 0 as lastPos
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CHARINDEX('&', @s, pos + 1), pos
      FROM splitter_cte
      WHERE pos > 0
      ),
    pair_cte AS (
    SELECT chunk,
           CHARINDEX('=', chunk) as pos
    FROM (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, lastPos + 1,
                         case when pos = 0 then 80000
                         else pos - lastPos -1 end) as chunk
        FROM splitter_cte) as t1
  )
    SELECT substring(chunk, 0, pos) as keyName,
           substring(chunk, pos+1, 8000) as keyValue
    FROM pair_cte
)
GO

declare @queryString varchar(2048)
set @queryString = 'foo=bar&temp=baz&key=value';
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.SplitQueryString(@queryString)
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

when run produces the following output.

```
keyName  keyValue

-------  --------

foo      bar

temp     baz

key      value

(3 row(s) affected)
```

I believe that this will do exactly what you are asking.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1c48/1)

Comment: your function is doing great , you've prepared an awesome function, but i wanted it to split with index of the  multiple instances of the   multiple special characters , because there is '¥' sign too. BTW ty :)

Answer (score 3):

How about using XML to split the values into rows, and then splitting them into columns.

Something like

```
Declare @qstr as varchar(max)='hireteammember.aspx?empemail=kuldeep@asselsolutions.com&empid=376&empname=kuldeep&adminname=TMA1&term=5&teamid=161&contactid=614¥1&WP=100¥5¥Months&Amt=500&DueDay=5&StrDt=12/31/2013&MemCatg=Employees&StrTm=21:05&PlnHrs=5&WrkDays=true¥true¥true¥true¥true¥false¥false'

DECLARe @str VARCHAR(MAX) = SUBSTRING(@qstr,CHARINDEX('?',@qstr,0) + 1, LEN(@qstr)-CHARINDEX('?',@qstr,0))
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT  @xml = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@str, '&', '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
        FROM    @xml.nodes('/d') T(split)
)
SELECT  LEFT(data,CHARINDEX('=',data,0) - 1),
        RIGHT(data,LEN(data) - CHARINDEX('=',data,0))
FROM    Vals
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27377)

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the values in the html string remains same i would suggest using the whole string name like

```
select ( SUBSTRING(@qstr,CHARINDEX('empemail=',@qstr)+1,CHARINDEX('&empid=',@qstr)-CHARINDEX('empemail=',@qstr)-1)))
```

If you are still looking for nth occurance then refer to [this link](http://sqlbisam.blogspot.com/2013/12/extract-data-from-delimited-column.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Declare @qstr as varchar(max)='hireteammember.aspx?empemail=kuldeep@asselsolutions.com&empid=376&empname=kuldeep&adminname=TMA1&term=5&teamid=161&contactid=614¥1&WP=100¥5¥Months&Amt=500&DueDay=5&StrDt=12/31/2013&MemCatg=Employees&StrTm=21:05&PlnHrs=5&WrkDays=true¥true¥true¥true¥true¥false¥false'

(select ( SUBSTRING(@qstr,CHARINDEX('&empname=',@qstr)+1,CHARINDEX('&adminname=',@qstr)-CHARINDEX('&empname=',@qstr)-1)))

(select ( SUBSTRING(@qstr,CHARINDEX('?empemail=',@qstr)+1,CHARINDEX('&empid=',@qstr)-CHARINDEX('?empemail=',@qstr)-1)))
```

**like this i have splitted and updated The whole string. Thank you All for your answers, Your answers Helped me to solve this**